# Geometric mean of 2 sets

Tags: statistics

If $2$ finite sets of positive integers have different cardinality but the same arithmetic mean, does the set with the greater number of elements always have a lower geometric mean?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you give more context: what do you think the answer is and why?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest counter example for the case of positive integers is probably
$$
A=\{1,3\} \qquad B=\{1,2,3\},
$$
both with arithmetic mean $2$. The geometric mean of $A$ is $\sqrt{3}\approx 1.73$, while that of $B$ is $6^{1/3}\approx 1.81$. Hence the geometric mean of the larger set ($B$) is larger than that of the smaller set ($A$).